# Recognize a number is typed twice in a row

Tags: java, for-loop, int

I need to make a program where the user is constantely asked if it can fill in a number and only when the user types a number twice in a row it will stop and print something like: "yeay!"
But I have no idea on what code i can use so it will recognize it has been typed twice. For now I had something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Type some numbers and dont forget to click enter after each number");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        if ( ...... ) {
            System.out.println("yeay");
            break;
        }else if (...){
            System.out.println("Type some numbers and dont forget to click enter after each number");
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know if it would be better to use a for-loop?

Comment: You need to have a variable containing the previously entered value. In your if block, compare the entered value with the previosuly entered one.

Comment: I didn't understood what you trying to do. Can you elaborate it more ?

Comment: The program keeps asking for a number, but only when a number is given twice in a row the program will stop asking you for a number. But how can the program stop when a number is typed twice in a row?

Comment: By storing the previously entered value in a variable, as I already explained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare a variable outside the loop and assign it to `number`. then next time check if the variable outside the loop is same as the new value entered.

here is an example:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
long previous = Long.MIN_VALUE;
while (true) {
     System.out.println("Type some numbers and dont forget to click enter after each number");
     int number = input.nextInt();
     if (previous == number) {
          System.out.println("yeay");
          break;
     }
     previous = number;
}
```